# All Inclusive file version merge

Tags: version-control, diff, patch, merge-conflict-resolution

Typical merge and source control tools mistake added code for code change especially if you merge several branches/version. Is there solution to merge several versions /branches of code without deleting a symbol? So the result of merge is interleaving of both files?

A use case one branch adds a fields and another branch adds a similar fields to website/api. The changes are practically isomorphic so might confuse a source code management tool.

Adding a non trivial field is typically tedious error prone task due MVC pattern and multi-layering, and involves adding some files, modifying other, lines and symbols yet deletion or swapping pieces of code is rarely needed. In fact I think to automate the task by having a generic patch/branch and just changing name and adding custom logic each time. I am aware one can code in way the adding of typical fields is push button task, or few lines change, yet not everybody likes such code.

Usually I use PyCharm (python version of IntellijIdea) or Smart Git for merging, but open to any tools or solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare can't automatically detect it, but in the Text Merge, you can manually take text from both sides using the right click **Take Left Then Right** or **Take Right Then Left** commands.

Comment: probably BC or similar tool support some automation, but will try